# Silverlight: Delay in Storyboard's Completed event handler

Tags: wpf, silverlight, animation, silverlight-4.0, storyboard

The storyBoard_Completed event is invoked in a delay of about half a second after the visual animation had finished.

Would be glad for some more eyes to check out my Storyboard XAML:

```
    <Storyboard x:Key="blaAnimation" Completed="storyBoard_Completed">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="bla1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset" Completed="bla_Completed">
            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" x:Name="bla1StartKeyFrame"/>

            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame Value="-10.2" KeyTime="0:0:1">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <PowerEase EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>

            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="-20" x:Name="bla1Animation">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <ElasticEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Oscillations="5" Springiness="20"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="bla2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset" BeginTime="0:0:0.1" Completed="bla2_Completed">
            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame Value="0" KeyTime="0:0:0.1" x:Name="bla2StartKeyFrame"/>

            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame Value="-10.2" KeyTime="0:0:1.1">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <PowerEase EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>

            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.1" Value="-20" x:Name="bla2Animation">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <ElasticEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Oscillations="5" Springiness="20"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="bla3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset" BeginTime="0:0:0.18" Completed="bla3_Completed">
            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame Value="0" KeyTime="0:0:0.2" x:Name="bla3StartKeyFrame"/>

            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame Value="-10.2" KeyTime="0:0:1.2">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <PowerEase EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>

            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.2" Value="-20" x:Name="bla3Animation">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <ElasticEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Oscillations="5" Springiness="20"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>


    </Storyboard>
```

Thanks in advance,
--Ran.

Comment: How long are you expecting it to animate for? The longest animation is 2.2 seconds (shortest is 2 seconds), so the storyboard should end 2.2 seconds after it starts. *Are you saying it executes the event at around 2.7 seconds or just that the animations end .5 seconds before the event triggers?* Without full XAML I can't tell if the animations are not just ending before you expected them too.

Comment: HiTech Magic, when playing it in Blend it's running 2.4 seconds exactly instead of 2.2 seconds. and it's also apparent when visually looking or playing some sounds at the finish. In order to give you a full XAML I'd have to wrap this storyboard in a standalone XAML as currently it's controlling a custom control. I thought maybe I'm missing something with this Storyboard declaration.

Comment: As you have Blend (which is good news) the 2.4 seconds is an indication that one of the individual changes is running longer than expected. If you set the time-slider position at 2.4 seconds are there any *changes* on that line? BTW the sounds are likely to have a start delay - add a visual indicator instead to check this instead of relying on the sounds.

Comment: HiTech Magic, Like it's now with the easing function it sets on the last value at 2.2 seconds and stays there for 0.2 seconds more. I've removed the easing function and scrolled through the animation again in Blend and I can see it's only getting to the target value (-20) in 2.4 seconds while at 2.2 seconds it didn't finish yet (-18), any ideas why?

Comment: OK, used your advice and played a bit more with the parameters in Blend and scrolled through the interpolated values. apparently I had two issues: first the BeginTime was adding a big delay at the end for some odd reason and secondly, the Easing function was reaching  the target value sooner than the KeyTime so it was just wait while nothing happens on screen. anyway Thanks for the Blend advice, didn't think going that way as I've (foolishly) originally created the animation manually without Blend's help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### When in doubt - Blend it

Following on from comment trail (above), the end result is ***"If you have access to it (or can afford it), always use Expression Blend for creating animation storyboards"***.

Blend is the best way to learn animation which can get very complex quite easily. Blend also optimises certainly animations automatically for you.

As you know there is no support at all in VS 2010 for authoring animation, except with XAML, and that is error prone. It is also very hard to visualise multiple animations in your head with only text to go by :)